# Validation for entry widget not behave as expected

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

I'm currently having multiple validation for different entry widget, and whilst all commands are set up the same way, only the validation for second entry work. Is there a reason why the other ones don't? Here's the part of my code dealing with entries:

```
import tkinter
from tkinter import *
import math
from tkinter import messagebox


class MyClass(tkinter.Frame):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        tkinter.Frame.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)

        #Setting up frame and widgets
        vcmd1 = (self.register(self.__vcmd1), '%P', '%S')
        vcmd2 = (self.register(self.__vcmd2), '%P')
        vcmd3 = (self.register(self.__vcmd3), '%P', '%S')

        self.v = IntVar()
        self.v.set(1)

        label_det = Label(self,text="Choose Detector")
        self.mcp0 = Radiobutton(self, text="MCP-0",variable=self.v,value=1,command=self.selected)
        self.mcp6 = Radiobutton(self, text="MCP-6",variable=self.v,value=2,command=self.selected)
        self.mpet = Radiobutton(self,text="MCP-MPET",variable=self.v,value=3,command=self.selected)

        label_det.grid(row=0, column=0, columnspan=2)
        self.mcp0.grid(row=1,columnspan=2)
        self.mcp6.grid(row=2,columnspan=2)
        self.mpet.grid(row=3,columnspan=2)

        label_iso = Label(self,text="Isotope A, Element (ex: 133,Cs)")
        label_vol = Label(self, text="Beam Energy (eV)")
        label_range = Label(self, text="Charge Range (ex:1,12)")

        label_iso.grid(row=4, column=0, sticky=E)
        label_vol.grid(row=5, column=0, sticky=E)
        label_range.grid(row=6, column=0, sticky=E)

        self.entry1 = tkinter.Entry(self, validate="key", validatecommand=vcmd1)
        self.entry2 = tkinter.Entry(self, validate="key", validatecommand=vcmd2)
        self.entry3 = tkinter.Entry(self, validate="key", validatecommand=vcmd3)

        self.entry1.grid(row=4, column=1)
        self.entry2.grid(row=5, column=1)
        self.entry3.grid(row=6, column=1)

    def __vcmd1(self, P, S):
        validString = 'qwertyuiopasdfghjklzxcvbnmQWERTYUIOPASDFGHJKLZXCVBNM,1234567890'
        if not S in validString:
            messagebox.showinfo("Error", "Not valid")
            return False
        if "," in P:
            messagebox.showinfo("Good", "Contain comma")
            if len(P.split(",")) > 2:
                messagebox.showinfo("Error", "Expected Form: ex. 133,Cs")
                return False
        else:
            return True

    def __vcmd2(self, P):
        if P == '':
            return True
        try:
            float(P)
            return True
        except ValueError:
            messagebox.showinfo("Error", "Entry must be a float or integer")
            return False


    def __vcmd3(self, P, S):
        if "," in P:
            if len(P.split(",")) > 2:
                messagebox.showinfo("Error", "Contain multiple commas")
                return False
            a = P.split(",")[0]
            b = P.split(",")[1]
            if a != '' and b != '':
                try:
                    int(a)
                    int(b)
                except ValueError:
                    messagebox.showinfo("Error", "Expected form: ex. 1,12")
                    return False
        else:
            return True

    def selected(self):
        if self.v.get() == 1:
            self.x = 8.0
        elif self.v.get() == 2:
            self.x = 3.0
        else:
            self.x = 9.2
        return self.x

class TimeGenerator:

    def __init__(self,master):

        self.frame = MyClass(master)
        self.frame.grid(columnspan=2)

        self.text = Text(root)
        self.iso = self.frame.entry1
        self.vol = self.frame.entry2
        self.r = self.frame.entry3

        button = Button(root, text='Time Range', command=self.calculateTime)
        button.grid(row=3, columnspan=2)

    def calculateTime(self):
        self.text.delete(1.0, END)

        dict = {'h': 1, 'he': 2, 'li': 3, 'be': 4, 'b': 5, 'c': 6, 'n': 7, 'o': 8, 'f': 9, 'ne': 10,
            'na': 11, 'mg': 12, 'al': 13, 'si': 14, 'p': 15, 's': 16, 'cl': 17, 'ar': 18,
            'k': 19, 'ca': 20, 'sc': 21, 'ti': 22, 'v': 23, 'cr': 24, 'mn': 25, 'fe': 26, 'co': 27, 'ni': 28,
            'cu': 29, 'zn': 30,
            'ga': 31, 'ge': 31, 'as': 33, 'se': 34, 'br': 35, 'kr': 36, 'rb': 37, 'sr': 38, 'y': 39,
            'zr': 40, 'nb': 41, 'mo': 42, 'tc': 43, 'ru': 44, 'rh': 45, 'pd': 46, 'ag': 47, 'cd': 48,
            'in': 49, 'sn': 50, 'sb': 51, 'te': 52, 'i': 53, 'xe': 54, 'cs': 55, 'ba': 56,
            'la': 57, 'ce': 58, 'pr': 59, 'nd': 60, 'pm': 61, 'sm': 62, 'eu': 63, 'gd': 64, 'tb': 65, 'dy': 66,
            'ho': 67, 'er': 68, 'tm': 69, 'yb': 70, 'lu': 71,
            'hf': 72, 'ta': 73, 'w': 74, 're': 75, 'os': 76, 'ir': 77, 'pt': 78, 'au': 79, 'hg': 80, 'tl': 81,
            'pb': 82, 'bi': 83, 'po': 84, 'at': 85, 'rn': 86,
            'fr': 87, 'ra': 88, 'ac': 89, 'th': 90, 'pa': 91, 'u': 92, 'np': 93, 'pu': 94, 'am': 95, 'cm': 96,
            'bk': 97, 'cf': 98, 'es': 99, 'fm': 100, 'md': 101, 'no': 102, 'lr': 103,
            'rf': 104, 'db': 105, 'sg': 106, 'bh': 107, 'hs': 108, 'mt': 109, 'ds': 110, 'rg': 111, 'cn': 112,
            'uut': 113, 'fl': 114, 'uup': 115, 'lv': 116, 'uus': 117, 'uuo': 118}

        if self.r.get() == "" or self.iso.get() == "" or self.vol.get() == "":
            messagebox.showinfo("Error", "No field can be empty")
            return None

        r = self.r.get().replace(" ", "")
        tup = tuple(int(x) for x in r.split(","))

        iso = self.iso.get().replace(" ", "")
        list = []
        for e in iso.split(","):
            list.append(e)

        if (dict[list[1].lower()] < tup[0]) or (dict[list[1].lower()] < tup[1]):
            messagebox.showinfo("Error", "Change state range does not exist for given element")
            return None

        f = open("/Users/LazyLinh/PycharmProjects/TimeGenGUI/mass.mas12.txt", "r")
        i = 0
        while (i < 40):
            header = f.readline()
            i += 1
        self.mass = 0

        #iterate through text file

        for line in f:
            line = line.strip()
            columns = line.split()
            if (list[0] == columns[3]):
                if (list[1].lower() == columns[4].lower()):
                    if (len(columns) == 16):
                        self.mass = float(columns[13].replace("#","")) + float(columns[14].replace("#",""))/10e6
                    else:
                        self.mass = float(columns[12].replace("#","")) + float(columns[13].replace("#",""))/10e6

        #Calculation

        list = []
        for q in range(tup[0], tup[1] + 1):
            y = (self.frame.selected() * math.sqrt(self.mass * 1.6605402e-27 / (2 * q *1.6022e-19 * float(self.vol.get())))) * 10e6
            list.append(y)
        i = tup[0]

        #inserting to text widget
        for time in list:
            self.text.insert("end", "%d: %s\n" % (i, time))
            i = i + 1
        self.text.grid()

        self.iso = self.frame.entry1
        self.vol = self.frame.entry2
        self.r = self.frame.entry3


root = Tk()
b = TimeGenerator(root)
root.mainloop()
```

observed errors include being able to add characters not from validString for entry 1, or being able to add multiple ',' for entry 3...

EDIT: I have included my full code and what I tried

Comment: Your code seems to work for me. I can't enter "!" or "@" in the first field, and errors pop up when I enter commas in the third field.  Have you tried adding debugging statements to see exactly which return statement is being used for each input?

Comment: @BryanOakley For 1st entry, the 'Contains comma' msgbox would show up, but not the 'Not Valid' or "Expected form', even if I enter invalid character or multiple comma. And for the 3rd entry, the 'Contains multiple commas' doesn't show up even if I used multiple commas, which is similar to 1st entry...

Comment: The only problem is a logic issue. There's nothing technically wrong with your code.  For example, if you enter an invalid character in the first field you don't even try to show a message.  You return `False`, which  causes tkinter to reject the edit. If you want a message to appear, you have to explicitly make that happen.

Comment: @BryanOakley In the full code version, I did have all the messagebox.showinfo before the return statement. Plus the problem is that I can still enter invalid characters and multiple commas and they'll show up in the entries, so tkinter does pass my edit instead of rejecting it...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code is technically working, though you have logic errors that perhaps are preventing it from working like you expect.

For the validation function to work, it *must* return either `True` or `False`. *Any other valid will disable the validation.* In your commands there are paths through the code that do not return `True` or `False`, causing the validation to be turned off.

For example, in `_vcmd`1, if `P` contains a comma but the expression `len(P.split(",")) > 2` is `False`, you end up returning `None` which will cancel any future validation.

Similarly, in `_vcmd3` you have a path through the code that returns `None`. Ask yourself what happens when you enter "4,". The function returns `None` which, again, cancels future validation.

Bottom line: your functions must *always* return either `True` or `False`, or validation will be turned off.